# Cocos2d-x in ios game using c++

Tags: ios, xcode, c++11, cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2d-x. I want to create multiple  buttons with different position. How can I achieve in c++?

Comment: Don't do this in code. Use CocosStudio for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to take a look at ui::Widget that can add to Node directly and does not need a extra layer such as CCMenu

Answer (score 0):

Create Multiple CCMenuItems and set position of individual items then create CCMenu and add items to CCMenu object afterwards add CCMenu to CCLayer object

Comment: suppose if have to create the 20 menuitems than.

Comment: you want to create 20 different menu items at 20 different locations. so you have to repeat the step 20 times

Comment: Arslan Mubashar Khan , yes, but i want to create into vector ,i mean only one object of 20 menu items i want to create.and i d'nt want to write the position 20 times.can you give me the code